# Java get decibel from Microphone

Tags: java, audio, microphone

I know there are some questions already like that but always only a part of the answer.

I just want to get the current decibels which are "recorded" by the microphone.
I got as far that i have opened a TargetDataLine but the read method only returns confusing bytes :/

Could you tell me how i can read the decibels?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in measuring, for example, [dB SPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure), This is not possible, at least not in the sense you probably mean. Here is one of several answers about using a computer mike to measure absolute sound intensity: [How can I calculate audio dB level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level)

If you are confused about what the bytes mean and are interested in, for example, measuring change in volume/sound intensity/something like that over time, that is doable, but it's a different question. There are many questions about how to interpret the raw data that comes out of javasound and other audio apis here on SO, but a better source is a tutorial. One good place to start is with some of the examples and tutorials over at [java sound resources](http://www.jsresources.org/). You might also be interested in my [slides from a talk on the basics of computer audio](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2011/11/slides-from-fundamentals-of-audio.html).

Comment: Okay thanks! But to define my problem: I want to run some code when a sudden loud noise appears, like when i'm clapping my hands. what's the best way to do that? And the reaction time should be as fast as possible...

Comment: I will open a new question for that...