# Is it possible to calculate dB level of an audio file?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I'm currently working on a project in C# and I want to know if it is possible to import a song
and measure the dB levels of the file.

For example: If a song is 3 minutes long I would want to divide the song into 5 
second sections and measure the dB of each part.

There is a relative calculation I can use which is

dB = 20 * log10(amplitude)

However, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level#) states that this formula is not accurate. I'm not a music
expert so before I go any further in this project I want to know **if their is any known way 
for me to accurately measure audio files through a program or can it only be measured in person**? (think studio-quality songs). If so, can you 
explain?

If there is a better formula to use in this context lmk :)

Please kindly comment if you don't understand my question. I understand that what may make
sense to me may not make sense to everyone else.

Comment: I don't think that answer says it is not accurate. It says that is it limited to providing you with an accurate measurement of the relative perceived loudness at the microphone, and subject to the microphone's response/sensitivity. If you need an absolute sound pressure measurement you'll need calibration data.

Comment: a sibling site focuses on digital signal processing ... here are some tips  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=calculate+db+level