# How to get audio file decibels without playing it?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a function which getting every sec of audio decibels. I tried to get them without playing the audio file but it has not worked.

JavaScript (playing audio to get decibels):

```js
export default function getAudio(a) {
  document.querySelector(`${a}`).addEventListener(
    "change",
    function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        var fileContent = reader.result;
        processAudio(fileContent);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    },
    false
  );

  function processAudio(url) {
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var audio = new Audio(url);
    var processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    var source;

    audio.addEventListener(
      "canplaythrough",
      function () {
        source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        source.connect(processor);
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        processor.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        audio.play();
      },
      false
    );

    processor.onaudioprocess = (evt) => {
      var input = evt.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      var len = input.length;
      var total = 0;
      var rms;
      var i = 0;

      while (i < len) total += Math.abs(input[i++]);
      rms = Math.sqrt(total / len);
      console.log(rms * 100);
      return rms * 100;
    };
  }
}

// In another script
getAudio('input') // With type file
```

I tried to use this:

JavaScript

```js
export default function getAudio(a) {
  document.querySelector(`${a}`).addEventListener(
    "change",
    function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        var fileContent = reader.result;
        processAudio(fileContent);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    },
    false
  );

  function processAudio(url) {
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var audio = new Audio(url);
    var processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    var source;

    audio.addEventListener(
      "canplaythrough",
      function () {
        source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        source.connect(processor);
        processor.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      },
      false
    );

    processor.onaudioprocess = (evt) => {
      var input = evt.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      var len = input.length;
      var total = 0; // Initialize total
      var rms;
      var i = 0; // Declare i

      while (i < len) total += Math.abs(input[i++]);
      rms = Math.sqrt(total / len);
      console.log(rms * 100);
      return rms * 100;
    };
  }
}
```

But I got thousands of zeros.

I also searched them on the internet but couldn't find useful results for me.

Note, that it would be better if decibels were placed in an array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level

Answer (score 1):

The `MediaElementAudioSource` is only providing whatever the audio element is currently playing as an input within the `AudioContext`. When the audio element is playing it will provide that signal. When the audio element is stopped it will be silent, too. Therefore it's only useful for realtime scenarios.

Maybe you're lucky and the audio file that you are using can be decoded by `decodeAudioData()`. In that case the following should work.

```js
audioCtx
    .decodeAudioData(url)
    .then((audioBuffer) => {
        const input = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);

        // you can then apply the same logic here
    });
```

Comment: Be better if it reads and logs decibels faster.