# MP3Gain like volume analyzer software for WAV files

Tags: c#, .net, wav

Coding Language: C#
Framework: .NET

We have built a software, which among many other things, combines mp3 files.
We are using a software called mp3Gain in our application.
[MP3Gain analyzes and adjusts mp3 files so that they have the same volume.](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/)

Now we are also combining "wav" files.
Would like to know if there is a similar software that analyzes and adjusts wav files so that they have the same volume.
Regards,
naveenj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a related question (with helpful links in some of the answers):

[How can I determine how loud a WAV file will sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984729/how-can-i-determine-how-loud-a-wav-file-will-sound)